# Assert that the function passed into a stubbed function is the correct function

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, sinon, stub

I'm trying to test my Node module using Mocha.

The module is very small here is an example...

```
import { sharedFunctionA, sharedFunctionB, commonFunction } from <file>

const functionA = token => _data => sharedFunctionA(token);
const functionB = () => data => sharedFunctionB(data);

exports.doThingA = token => {
  commonFunction(functionA(token));
};

exports.doThingB = () => {
  commonFunction(functionB());
};
```

This is only a brief example but it shows what I'm trying to do.

I need to test that `doThingA` and `doThingB` pass in the correct function to the `commonFunction`.

I have stubbed the `commonFunction` and I can see that it is being called but I can't assert that the function passed in is correct.

TBH... I'm beginning to think of restructuring this entirely to pass in some sort of enum to the `commonFunction` and running the respective function from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you can stub on the `sharedFunctionA` and `sharedFunctionB` and then retrieve the argument of your stub on the `commonFunction` and call it. Then check your other stubs are being called with the desired arguments.

I know it's tedious but it is the only way I can think of with your code.

Quick example:

```
const assert = require('assert')
const sinon = require('sinon')
const sharedFunctions = require('<fileWithSharedFunctions>')
const commonStub = sinon.stub(sharedFunctions, 'commonFunction')
const sharedBStub = sinon.stub(sharedFunctions, 'sharedFunctionB')

const fileToTest = require('<fileToTest>')

fileToTest.doThingB()
commonStub.getCall(0).args[0]()
assert(sharedBStub.calledOnce)
```

Comment: Ah! I didn’t think of that. Thanks, I’ll give that a go.

Comment: I did it a very slightly different way but got it working now. Thanks :D